# Argument 'rows' has incorrect type (expected list, got tuple) - In Python

Tags: pandas, list, loops, tuples

Hi i'm trying to create a list to use in a range in a for loop, here is my code in pyhton

```
from pandas import DataFrame
 q_rt_1 = "select DISTINCT yearmonth from master.txns "\
             "where yearmonth is not null "\
             "order by yearmonth asc "

cursor.execute(q_rt_1)
df= DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
list_of_periodos = df[0].to_list()
```

But Im getting this **error**:
"Argument 'rows' has incorrect type (expected list, got tuple)"

The "for" goes like this:

```
for x in list_of_periodos:
    col = str(x) + "_ym"
    q_rt_5 = "alter table retention.activation_matrix add column " + col + " int(6)"
    cursor.execute(q_rt_5)
```

### Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and what should I correct?
I get this from the query:

```
yearmonth
201509
201510
201511
201512
201601
201602
201603
201604
201605
201606
201607
201608
201609
201610
201611
201612
201701
201702
201703
201704
201705
201706
201707
201708
201709
201710
201711
201712
201801
201802
201803
201804
201805
201806
201807
```

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset that you are getting from the SQL query so we can reproduce it

Comment: Done, I put a part of the result of the query above

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.fetchall()` returns tuples of tuple.

Try this:

```
data = cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=list(data), columns=['yearmonth'])
```